# How to filtering F5 monitors with python script and bigsuds

Tags: python, f5

i try to filter a list of monitors to keep only those that contain a specific string of characters.
I get a list with my function.

```py
import bigsuds
import re
import string

def get_monitors(obj):
    try:
        return obj.LocalLB.Monitor.get_template_list()
    except Exception, e:
        print e

try:
    b = bigsuds.BIGIP(
            hostname = "F5.serveur.com",
            username = "user",
            password = "password",
            )

except Exception, e:
    print e

monitors = get_monitors(b)
```

Here is an example of a result :

```py
[{'template_type': 'TTYPE_DIAMETER', 'template_name': '/Common/diameter'}, {'template_type': 'TTYPE_DNS', 'template_name': '/Common/dns'}, {'template_type': 'TTYPE_HTTP', 'template_name': '/Common/namexxxxx'}]
```

I need to filter this list to keep only items containing "Common \ name"

I try for exemple :

```py
moniteur_ok = list(filter(lambda x: 'Common\name' in x, monitors))

or

moniteur_ok = re.findall(r'(?<=\s)/Common/name\S+' ,monitors)
```

Ideas to filter according to my needs ?

I could then recover via my F5 some info.

```py
monitor_property= b.LocalLB.Monitor.get_template_string_property(["\Common\namexxxxx"],["STYPE_SEND"],["STYPE_RECEIVE"],["STYPE_TIMEOUT_PACKETS"])
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier just to set your active partition (**set_active_partition** method) and grab only the Common monitors. Here's an example that loops through all the partitions and prints the monitors in each:

```
>>> partitions = b.Management.Partition.get_partition_list()
>>> for partition in partitions:
...     print "\t{}".format(partition['partition_name'])
...     b.Management.Partition.set_active_partition(active_partition=partition['partition_name'])
...     mons = b.LocalLB.Monitor.get_template_list()
...     for mon in mons:
...         print "\t\t{}".format(mon['template_name'])
...         
    Common
        /Common/none
        /Common/diameter
        /Common/external
        /Common/firepass
        /Common/ftp
        /Common/gateway_icmp
        /Common/http
        /Common/http_head_f5
        /Common/https
        /Common/https_443
        /Common/https_head_f5
        /Common/icmp
        /Common/imap
        /Common/inband
        /Common/ldap
        /Common/module_score
        /Common/mssql
        /Common/mysql
        /Common/nntp
        /Common/oracle
        /Common/pop3
        /Common/postgresql
        /Common/radius
        /Common/radius_accounting
        /Common/real_server
        /Common/rpc
        /Common/sasp
        /Common/scripted
        /Common/sip
        /Common/smb
        /Common/smtp
        /Common/snmp_dca
        /Common/snmp_dca_base
        /Common/soap
        /Common/tcp
        /Common/tcp_echo
        /Common/tcp_half_open
        /Common/udp
        /Common/dns
        /Common/virtual_location
        /Common/wap
        /Common/wmi
        /Common/mqtt
        /Common/myhttp
    bc
        /bc/new_http_test
    mc
        /mc/new_http_test
    part1
    part2
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer, I took example on your answer. I have also created functions to retrieve data from a monitor. Then, I will build a json file to display the data with Datables for example :

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import bigsuds
import re
import datetime
import json

# Fonction pour recuperer les strings d'un moniteur
def get_moniteur_type(obj, monitor):
    try:
        return obj.LocalLB.Monitor.get_template_type([monitor])[0]
    except Exception, e:
        print e

# Fonction pour recuperer les strings d'un moniteur
def get_stype_string(obj, monitor, stype):
    try:
        return obj.LocalLB.Monitor.get_template_string_property([monitor],[stype])[0]['value']
    except Exception, e:
        print e

# Fonction reverse sur la reponse attendue a un test applicatif, si true, on ne doit pas avoir la reponse indiquee dans la receive string
def get_reverse_mode(obj, monitor):
    try:
       return obj.LocalLB.Monitor.get_template_reverse_mode([monitor])[0]
    except Exception, e:
        print e

# Fonction pour recuperer l'intervalle et le timeout d'un moniteur
def get_itype_string(obj, monitor, itype):
    try:
        return obj.LocalLB.Monitor.get_template_integer_property([monitor],[itype])[0]['value']
    except Exception, e:
        print e

# Fonction pour recuperer le port utilise par le moniteur
def get_moniteur_port(obj, monitor):
    try:
        return obj.LocalLB.Monitor.get_template_destination([monitor])[0]['ipport']['port']
    except Exception, e:
        print e

# Information de connexion au F5
try:
    b = bigsuds.BIGIP(
            hostname = "server-f5.domaine",
            username = "user",
            password = "password",
            )

except Exception, e:
    print e

#On recupere tous les moniteurs present dans la partition Common, qui est l'emplacement des moniteurs crees par le reseau
b.Management.Partition.set_active_partition(active_partition='Common')
noms_long = b.LocalLB.Monitor.get_template_list()
#On boucle sur les noms des moniteurs en filtrant ceux crees pour dune
for nom in noms_long:
#On supprime \Common\ dans le nom long pour avoir le nom du moniteur
    moniteur = format(nom['template_name'])[8:]
#On ne va recuperer que les moniteurs qui commencent par"startname"
    if re.match(r'^startname', moniteur):

        print "{ \"moniteur\": \"",moniteur,"\", \"type\": \"",get_moniteur_type(b, moniteur),"\", \"requette_http\": \"",get_stype_string(b, moniteur, "STYPE_SEND"),"\", \"reponse_attendue\": \"",get_stype_string(b, moniteur, "STYPE_RECEIVE"),"\", \"mode_reverse\": \"",get_reverse_mode(b, moniteur),"\", \"timeout\": \"",get_itype_string(b, moniteur, "ITYPE_TIMEOUT"),"\", \"intervale\": \"",get_itype_string(b, moniteur, "ITYPE_INTERVAL"),"\", \"port\": \"",get_moniteur_port(b, moniteur),"\", \"type\": \"",get_moniteur_type(b, moniteur),"\"},"
```

In this example, what interests me is to recover on an application test, the request sent and the answer expected or not, but globally, I can have tests on a particular port or UDP tests. It's all about having the main data.